# Using UIPickerView and Label: How to use it effectively

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I am making a app with `UIPickerView`. (shown in the image below)
[image]

I want to choose the course and let them show in the table listed above. The tricky part is how to fill the label (listed as "Course to fill") according to `UIPickerView` selection. Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)addCourse:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSInteger numRow=[picker selectedRowInComponent:kNumComponent];//0=1st,1=2nd,etc
    NSInteger SeaRow=[picker selectedRowInComponent:kSeaComponent];//0=fall,1=spring,2=summer
    NSInteger CourseRow=[picker selectedRowInComponent:kCourseComponent];

    NSString *num=Number[numRow];
    NSString *season=Season[SeaRow];
    NSString *course=Course[CourseRow];


    NSString *labelName;

    while (i<4) {

    for(row in numRow){
    labelName="_courseLabel"+row +[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];//labelName to store the labels in the table

            i++;}
    }

}
```

It has errors, and I am sure it is not the best option, any idea to improve it please?

An example to fill in one of the `UILabel` is listed below, but I don't know the best option to fill in all of the labels in the responding tables.

```
- (IBAction)addCourse:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSInteger numRow=[picker selectedRowInComponent:kNumComponent];//0=1st,1=2nd,etc
    NSInteger SeaRow=[picker selectedRowInComponent:kSeaComponent];//0=fall,1=spring,2=summer
    NSInteger CourseRow=[picker selectedRowInComponent:kCourseComponent];

    NSString *course=Course[CourseRow];

    NSString *msg=[[NSString alloc ]initWithFormat:@"%@ ",course];
    _courseLabel.text=[msg substringToIndex:8];

}
```

Main target:  For example, if in the UIPickerView, one choose 1st and "CHEM 3511", then in the table with the cell labeled as 1st, the label shown as "Course to fill" will be replaced by "CHEM 3511", then the user can continue to choose course from the UIPickerView and replace the "Course to fill" in the responding cell.

Comment: This can't be all of your code to accomplish this... Could you please post all of the relevant code? And what do you want the result string to say?

Comment: Hi Lyndsey, thanks for your reply again. I have added some related code. What I want in the string (listed as "course to fill") is from the result from the pickerView selection. But I don't know the best option to do it.

Comment: Your loop/while block is still incomplete and you've done nothing with labelName...

Comment: Oh, I see. So the update is also the same method... But what result are you looking for exactly.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I am just looking for the best method show my selection result from the pickerview in the labels (shown as "course to fill"). Please ignore the first method, it is a little bit mess up.

Comment: You still need to specify *exactly* what you want the label/labels to say so people can help you know what data to include, etc...

Comment: Please see my last edit, the main target part. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: OK, you should implement the table view delegate methods then and use addCourse to add the course to your table's data model.

Comment: Any example I  can learn from the website please?